# Ruby segmentation fault after updating Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rbenv

I'm using:

- rbenv with ruby versions 1.9.3-p448 and 2.0.0-p247
- rails 3.2.13

I made some update (rails updated to 3.2.14) and when i started rails `server` or `console` i get a brutal segmentation fault:

```
iwan $ rails s
/Users/iwan/dev/rails/pivotality_3/vendor/bundle/gems/debugger-1.6.1/lib/ruby_debug.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
...
```

Tried to remove some gem but without success. I searched for a solution a couple of hours...

Answer (score 0):

Drop you `vendor/bundle/` directory and reinstall gems with `bundle install`

Problem fixed!